# Aligning three SPAN/DIV tags - fixed left, fixed right, fill middle

Tags: css, html

I want three `<div>` or `<span>` tags in a line.

- Left = a 57px width image
- Right = a 57px image
- Centre = A span image to fill the whole width.

```
<div class="bar-left"></div>
<div class="bar-span"></div>
<div class="bar-right"></div>
```

I'm drawing a fancy `hr` line where each end fades out. I can get the left and right images aligned using `float: left;` and `float: right;` but the middle seems impossible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Would this be ok?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F2WVL/)

The idea is to put left and right column on top and float them, then put margin to the content `div` so it doesn't wrap under floated ones...

```
<div class="bar-left"></div>
<div class="bar-right"></div>
<!- content goes in last -->
<div class="bar-span"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bar-left
{
    float: left;
    width: 57px;
}

.bar-right
{
    float:right;
    width: 57px;
}

.bar-span
{
    margin: 0 70px;
}
```

Comment: Great stuff - many thanks. For the bar-span I naturally had to use **margin: 0 57px;**, but I can forgive you a typo ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Put your floated divs before the non-floated ones:

```
<div class="bar-left" style="float: left; color: blue; background-color: blue; width: 57px;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bar-right" style="float: right; width: 57px; background-color: blue;">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="bar-span" style="background-color: green; display: block;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

traditionally, when you want to line things up like this end-to-end, you float *all* of them left or right.